# Java change legend chart + get color of graph

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-2

I have 2 questions.
I made a program that makes charts but the legend it is not realy clear. 
I already enlarged the icons (in css) but I would like to fill them up with the same color like there border.

Now question 2. I would like to set the background of my cells to the same color as the matching line in the graph is there a way I can ask what color a line is in the graph?

[My program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqf3Z.png)

---

```
 list.add(w2+" ("+percent+"%)");
 months.keySet().forEach((it) -> {
      series.getData().add(newXYChart.Data(it.toString().substring(0, 7), months.get(it)));
 });
 series.setName(w2);
 graph.getData().add(series);
 graphs.put(w2, series);
```

I make a XYChart and save it in a hashmap. The tag I put in the hashmap I put in the lisview on the right.

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: What part of the code do you want?

Comment: The part that generates/displays the chart/graph.  We cannot help you if you don't provide the code that is causing a problem for you.

Comment: I hope this small part is good enough? If not you can find the full class here https://pastebin.com/ef7fsFek